# How do i fix this if/else statement so there is no argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I'm a beginner at rails and am trying to create a very basic Todo list application.

For my view for the `show action` for viewing an individual Todo list I am trying to write an if/else statement that when the `complete_by` date is empty (as some people might not want a specific list to have a complete by date) it states that there is no complete by date, whether if the `complete_by` had a date, it would state the date.

Here is my form for creating a new list:

[image]

and here is my code (in /app/views/lists/show.html.erb)

```
<h2><%= @list.title %></h2>
<% if @list.complete_by(presence: false) %>
    <h4>This list has no completion date</h4>
<% else %>
    <h4>To be completed by: <%= @list.complete_by %></h4>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', lists_path %>
```

I know that the `<% if @list.complete_by(presence: false) %>` line is incorrect, but how do I make it so that there will be no argument error like so:[image]

Thank you for your time,

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.nil?` to check if a value is `nil`.

```
<% if @list.complete_by.nil? %>
  <h4>This list has no completion date</h4>
<% else %>
  <h4>To be completed by: <%= @list.complete_by %></h4>
<% end %>
```

You can also take advantage of the nil-to-false evaluation by swapping the conditions:

```
<% if @list.complete_by %>
  <h4>To be completed by: <%= @list.complete_by %></h4>
<% else %>
  <h4>This list has no completion date</h4>
<% end %>
```

or (a little bit less readable)

```
<% if !@list.complete_by %>
  <h4>This list has no completion date</h4>
<% else %>
  <h4>To be completed by: <%= @list.complete_by %></h4>
<% end %>
```